# Setting height for one individual cell in Xcode swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

Hey I am creating a tableview with multiple dynamic cells. I want one cell to be a different size then all the others ones but I am unsure on how to exactly execute the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method. Is anyone able to walk me through what to do?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if ( indexPath.row % 8 == 7 ) {
        // I want height to equal 20
    }
    return //not sure what I am supposed to return
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You're returning the height as a CGFloat

Comment: So in your if statement, `return 20.0` and outside of it at the bottom `return otherHeight`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement this delegate method, you must handle every row of the table:

- To make the height 20, return 20 (as a CGFloat).
- The default height is `tableView.rowHeight`, so to make the height the default height, return that.